# Is it possible to encapsulate some PHP code to avoid try/catch repetitions?

Tags: php

See this PHP code snippet:

```
try {
    /* do something */
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

try {
    /* do something else */
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

try {
    /* do something other */
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The desired scenario:

```
function run($code) {
    try {
        << execute $code >>;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

run({ /* do something */ });
run({ /* do something else */ });
run({ /* do something other */ });
```

Is it possible to codify something like this WITHOUT create more named functions on PHP?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Though you may want to rethink that philosophy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use anonymous functions :

```
<?php
function run($code) {
    try {
        $code();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

// Simple anonymous function
run(function ()
{
    echo "Hello" . PHP_EOL;
    throw new Exception("1 throws");
});

// Anonymous function stored in a variable
$somePieceOfCode = function ()
{
    echo "Hello 2" . PHP_EOL;
    throw new Exception("2 throws");
};

run($somePieceOfCode);

// Use external variables in the anonymous function
$message = "Hello";
$number = 3;

run(function () use ($message, $number)
{
    echo "$message $number" . PHP_EOL;
    throw new Exception("3 throws");
});

// Store and execute your anonymous functions in an array
$functionArray = [
    function ()
    {
        echo "Array 1" . PHP_EOL;
        throw new Exception("Array 1 throws");
    },
    function ()
    {
        echo "Array 2" . PHP_EOL;
        throw new Exception("Array 2 throws");
    },
    function ()
    {
        echo "Array 3" . PHP_EOL;
        throw new Exception("Array 3 throws");
    }
];

foreach ($functionArray as $func)
{
    run($func);
}
```

This outputs :

```
Hello
1 throws
Hello 2
2 throws
Hello 3
3 throws
Array 1
Array 1 throws
Array 2
Array 2 throws
Array 3
Array 3 throws
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function name as an argument to your try-catch routine.
This is a nice feature of the PHP and it is called "[variable functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)".
Here is a code [example](http://ideone.com/qAC1fD).

```
<?php

function run($fun) {    
  try{
    $fun();
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}

run('myFirst');
run('mySecond');
run('myThird');


function myFirst() {
  echo "My first method\n";
}

function mySecond() {
  echo "My second method\n";
}

function myThird() {
  echo "My third method\n";
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion solved my problem too, but according the question Cid answered me what exactly I needed. Thank you for your answer as an alternative! I will use this tip a lot starting now.